# SQL select query value that are not there in DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a list say ("apple","banana","orange") . I want to find which if these column values is not available in a column called "name" under the table called "fruit".

I want the SQL for DB2 database

Comment: BTW, "name" is a poor column name, "fruitname" is better, or just "fruit" in "fruits" table. (Singularis for column names, pluralis for table names.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I didnt want to paste the actual business column names, hence gave you some random names. Anyways I got the answer. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name 
FROM (
    VALUES  ('apple'),('banana'),('orange')
) t1(name) 
where t1.name not in (Select name from fruit)
```

Comment: Is this a solution or a part of the question? Please [edit] and describe your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a matter of preference, consider using an "exception join"

```
SELECT t1.name  
FROM ( 
    VALUES ('apple'),('banana'),('orange') 
) t1(name)  
EXCEPTION JOIN fruit ON fruit.name = t1.name
```

NOTE: if you instead use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" (as shown below), the rows with NULL values for fruit columns will still indicate the values absent from the fruit table, but you will also see all of the data associated with the fruit rows that are matched:

```
SELECT t1.name , fruit.* 
FROM ( 
    VALUES ('apple'),('banana'),('orange') 
) t1(name)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN fruit on fruit.name = t1.name
```